# Cell Style Binding does not Update on Value Change

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a DataGrid which is bound to a Collection of Objects. Every DataGridColumn is created in code behind.

The Background of these columns is dependent on different values of the object. I create the background binding in the CellStyle (as it should not override default style's from triggers).

```
var backgroundBinding = new Binding         
{
    Converter = new MyBindingConverter(),
    ConverterParameter = new MyConverterParameter()
};
cellStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(Control.BackgroundProperty, backgroundBinding));
```

As you can see it binds directly to the element. As different value are changing the value of the Columns is updated accordingly, but the converter of the Binding is not called. 
I tried calling `OnPropertyChanged(null)` to show that the object was updated, but sadly this does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to specify `Path` for backgroundBinding? Something like:

```
var backgroundBinding = new Binding         
{
    Converter = new MyBindingConverter(),
    ConverterParameter = new MyConverterParameter(),
    ElementName = YourElementName,
    Path = PropertyOnElement
};
cellStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(Control.BackgroundProperty, backgroundBinding));
```

Comment: I need it directly bound to the elment. But I tried it, and it didn't change a thing.

Comment: Could you please elaborate, on what to set the ElementName?

Comment: You said that you need bound your backgroundBinding to the element. So you have to set `Name` attribute on your element - `<YourElement x:Name="YourElementName">`. Than use this name in your backgroundBinding - `ElementName = "YourElementName"`.

Comment: Seems like I made a translation error, sorry. I mean bound to the object/Item of the DataGridRow.